# cocoa touch: animate button on touch

Tags: cocoa, animation, button, touch

I have a full screen button (which I placed in IB) with an image that I want to slide off screen when the user clicks on it. I know the connections are ok as I can log something when the button is clicked. But this code, which I have used before to move UIViews and UIImageViews is not working.

```
-(void) movePatch : (id) sender { 

  mainImg =[[UIButton alloc] init];

 //firing up animation
 [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL]; 
 //setting animation speed
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0   ];

 [mainImg setFrame:CGRectMake (-320.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)];

 //running animations
 [UIView commitAnimations];

 //release mainImg
 [mainImg release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is all the code, there are two things you need to consider;

1. the mainImg (which is inappropriately named, becuase it is a button) is not placed on the view ([self.view addSubview:mainImg])
2. I don't think you should release right after the commit. I think you should do this at the animations' 'didStopSelector', and thus make it an ivar.

Comment: Thanks MiRAGe. The button was added in IB and in my .h file as IBOutlet NSButton* mainImg, do I still have to add it to the view as you suggested? so you think releasing it here is destroying it before the CA has a chance to move its location? (I know the naming is off but I was working a bunch of different scenarios to see what worked best and got tired of renaming it).

Comment: if you have it as an IBOutlet, do not create and destroy it in that function at all. it should work without that code. release in the dealloc or viewDidUnload.